# How to set Image from Uri with a file:// scheme

Tags: java, android, uri

I managed to use myimageview.setImageUri when the scheme was content://
But it doesnt work if my Uri has a file:// scheme. What is wrong and how can I make it work?

I have given both read and write permission.

Edit:

To make sure I haven't messed up anything, I created a whole new project.

Mainactivity:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    ArrayList<Uri> myimageUri = null;
    myimageUri = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    Uri theuri = myimageUri.get(0);
    ImageView myimageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    myimageView.setImageURI(theuri);
}
```

Attaching a debugger I found out that theuri is

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Images/IMG-20171101-WA0005.jpg
```

It still doesn't work, but content :/// URIs work.

Comment: Are there any error messages? Also post the code you tried

Comment: @NabinBhandari I have updated the post with my code. There are no errors and no esceptions thrown. It also doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode image file to a bitmap and give it to ImageView.

```
Bitmap  mBitmap = Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), yourUri); 
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: bitmap is always null is I use uri.toString to get the path.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
InputStream in = myimageView.g etContext().getContentResolver(). openInputStream(theuri);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
in.close();
myimageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```